# How could I solve this set of two variable second order and first order linear differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning about differential equations in my math class (still on the basics) while taking a controls engineering class and have now encountered differential equations in the controls engineering class which I dont know how to solve using my current math tools.

Firstly, I can tell you what I am actually modelling. Its not directly relevant for the question which is about how to solve a set of first and second order differential equations, but I think its useful to know how I actually ended up with the set of equations. If it is not a good habit to include extra information like this, please tell me and I will remove the extra information from the post.

#### The system I am modelling

What I am modelling is a two tank system where I am supposed to regulate the height in tank 2. There is a drawing beneath of how the system looks.

[Drawing of how the system looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR9zd.png)

The differential equations describe the heights ($h_1$ and $h_2$) in each tank is given by:

$$\dot{h_1} = \frac{1}{ρA_{b1}}(ω_{in1}-ω_{out1})$$

$$\dot{h_2} = \frac{1}{ρA_{b2}}(ω_{in2}-ω_{out2})$$

where $ρ$ is the mass density of the water, $A_{b1}$ and $A_{b1}$ are the bottom areas of tank 1 and 2 (they are cylinder shaped). $ω$ represents mass flow where:

$$ω_{in1} = K_pe+K_i\int_0^t e\,dT + K_d\dot{e}$$

$$ω_{out1} = w_{in2} = ρA_{p1}\sqrt{2gh_1}$$

$$ω_{out2} = ρA_{p2}\sqrt{2gh_2}$$

$A_{p1}$ and $A_{p2}$ are the areas of the pipes from tank 1 to tank 2 and out from tank 2 respectively. g is the gravitational constant.
$ω_{in1}$ is the output a regulator which outputs a mass flow of water (its represented as a valve in the drawing). $e$ is in this case the deviation between a reference height $h_2$ and its reference value $r_{h2}$, so: $e = r_{h2} - h_2$. To make the equations easier to solve I linearized $ω_{out2}$ and $ω_{out1} = w_{in2}$ around the middle height of the tanks:

$$ω_{out1} = w_{in2} = K_1h_1 + C_1$$
$$ω_{out2} = K_2h_2 + C_2$$

where $K_1,K_2,C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants determined during the linearization. This means you can write the differential equations as:

$$\dot{h_1} = \frac{1}{ρA_{b1}}(K_pe+K_i\int_0^t e\,dT + K_d\dot{e} - K_1h_1-C_1)$$

$$\dot{h_2} = \frac{1}{ρA_{b2}}(K_1h_1-K_2h_2+C_1-C_2)$$

#### My mathematical problem

I now have the differential equations:

$$\dot{h_1} = \frac{1}{ρA_{b1}}(K_pe+K_i\int_0^t e\,dT + K_d\dot{e} - K_1h_1-C_1)$$

$$\dot{h_2} = \frac{1}{ρA_{b2}}(K_1h_1-K_2h_2+C_1-C_2)$$

But I am not certain of how to solve it. Firstly I tried to combine the equations in to a single one. I did this by taking the derivative on each side of the $\dot{h_1}$ equation like this:
$$\ddot{h_1} = \frac{1}{ρA_{b1}}(K_p\dot{e} + K_ie + K_d\ddot{e}-K_1\dot{h_1})$$
And since:
$$e=r_{h2} - h_2$$
$$\dot{e} = -\dot{h_2}$$
$$\ddot{e} = -\ddot{h_2}$$

This means:

I              $$ρA_{b1}\ddot{h_1}=-K_d\ddot{h_2}-K_p\dot{h_2}-K_i{h_2}-K_1\dot{h_1}+K_ir_{h2}$$

The $\dot{h_2}$ equation can be rewritten like this:
$$h_1 = \frac{1}{K_1}(ρA_{b2}\dot{h_2} + K_2h_2) + C_2-C_1$$

If I now take the derivative two times of each side of this equation, I will end up with $\ddot{h_1}$ on the left side and a expression containing $\dddot{h_2}$ on the right side. This means I could replace $\dot{h_1}$ and $\ddot{h_1}$ in equation I and end up with a third order differential equation which I think I can solve. I could then use the solution of $h_2$ to solve for $h_1$.

My questions are:

1. Would this method of taking the derivative of each side work for solving the equation?
2. Is there another and easier way to solve this equation?
3. I linearized the original differential equation to make it easier to solve. Would it be a lot harder to solve it using the non-linear root terms? This would make the model more accurate for larger tanks, but I have never solved non-linear differential equations before.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.